# Livecycle RegEx error with character length

Tags: javascript, regex, livecycle

I'm trying to get a regex to work in Livecycle. I have the code under the change event of the text field and language set to JavaScript. The code is:

```
if (xfa.event.newText.match(/^[0-9]{5}$/))      
{
xfa.event.change = "";
}
```

The problem is the text field is accepting any number of alphanumeric characters OR only 4 numeric characters.

This isjust the first part of the regex, the full piece will be (EC+3 digits, C+4 digits, 5 digits) `/[e][c][0-9]{3}|[c][0-9]{4}|[0-9]{5}/i` but I wanted to test the functionality first.

Comment: What error do you get? This seems fine to me.

Comment: It's not giving me an error, it's just letting me enter alpha characters with no limit OR only 4 numeric characters.

Comment: Oh, add `^` and `$` to your regexp. Incase the `|` is not matching what you want, add some brackets `()`.

Comment: `/^[e][c][0-9]{3}|([c][0-9]{4})|([0-9]{5})&/` is still not returning what is expected in Livecyvle.

Comment: Can you give sample input that doesn't give the right result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex basically says "if the new text after the change you made is equal to ##### (where # is some number) then don't allow that change."  This means it will allow any other changes, including letters, etc.

So it's pretty much the opposite of what you want to see.

The change event fires each time the user enters another character, so if you want this to work it has to accept each step of the characters. Example - E is ok, EC is ok, EC1 is ok, but ECC is not ok.

Edit - at first I was going to recommend you check this in the exit/validate event instead of on change, but I thought about it a bit more and the regex pattern to format upon change is actually not that bad. If you put this code in the change event it should prevent the user from typing in anything that does not meet one of these 3 formats.

EC###, C####, #####

```
if (!xfa.event.newText.match(/^(e|ec|ec\d{1,3}|c|c\d{1,4}|\d{1,5})$/i))
{
    xfa.event.change = "";
}
```

(The pattern is case insensitive, if you want it case sensitive remove the i at the end.)